# gtsummary table footnote missing in knitted pdf

Tags: r-markdown, gtsummary

I tried to knit my Rmarkdown report as PDF, and I noticed that the footnote is not there anymore. What did I miss?

```
  stats_summary_table <-
    dat %>%
    tbl_summary(by = id, 
                missing = "no",
                digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(0, 0, 1, 1, 3)),
                type = list(all_numeric() ~ "continuous"),
                statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ 
                                   "{min} ~ {max} {mean} ± {sd} [{cv}]")) %>%
      modify_footnote(starts_with("stat_") ~ "Range and mean±SD [cv]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF output with the gt package is still under development. Can you please confirm the footnotes work properly with PDF output using only the gt package? That will tell us if the issue lies within gt or gtsummary.

In the meantime, may I suggest you utilize one of the other print engines supported by the gtsummary package (gt is the default)
http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html

[image]